# Prevent request too quickly in bash

Tags: bash, ssh, docker, sleep

I have to enable, start, stop and restart docker in a bash script.
The problem is that the command's are executed with an ssh-connection. So after executing the command the ssh-connection closes. So there is not enough time to start and stop docker. I get this error:

> start request repeated too quickly for docker.service

How can I prevent this?
Is it possible to perform a `sleep` in the same command

```
 ${SSHKEY}$i sudo systemctl start docker
 ${SSHKEY}$i sleep 4
```

The above does not work because the connection closes.
I tried:

```
${SSHKEY}$i sudo systemctl start docker; sleep 1
```

But didn't seem to work because the connection closes immediately after the first command .

Answer (score 1):

Read the docs and manual pages. Systemd has pretty neat one: [systemd.service](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html):

> **StartLimitInterval=**, **StartLimitBurst=**
>
> Configure service start rate limiting. By default, services which are started more than 5 times within 10 seconds are not permitted to start any more times until the 10 second interval ends. With these two options, this rate limiting may be modified. Use StartLimitInterval= to configure the checking interval (defaults to DefaultStartLimitInterval= in manager configuration file, set to 0 to disable any kind of rate limiting). Use StartLimitBurst= to configure how many starts per interval are allowed (defaults to DefaultStartLimitBurst= in manager configuration file). These configuration options are particularly useful in conjunction with Restart=; however, they apply to all kinds of starts (including manual), not just those triggered by the Restart= logic. Note that units which are configured for Restart= and which reach the start limit are not attempted to be restarted anymore; however, they may still be restarted manually at a later point, from which point on, the restart logic is again activated. Note that systemctl reset-failed will cause the restart rate counter for a service to be flushed, which is useful if the administrator wants to manually start a service and the start limit interferes with that.
>
> **StartLimitAction=**
>
> Configure the action to take if the rate limit configured with StartLimitInterval= and StartLimitBurst= is hit. Takes one of none, reboot, reboot-force, reboot-immediate, poweroff, poweroff-force or poweroff-immediate. If none is set, hitting the rate limit will trigger no action besides that the start will not be permitted.  reboot causes a reboot following the normal shutdown procedure (i.e. equivalent to systemctl reboot).  reboot-force causes a forced reboot which will terminate all processes forcibly but should cause no dirty file systems on reboot (i.e. equivalent to systemctl reboot -f) and reboot-immediate causes immediate execution of the reboot(2) system call, which might result in data loss. Similar, poweroff, poweroff-force, poweroff-immediate have the effect of powering down the system with similar semantics. Defaults to none.

Basically you need to set these options to suit your needs in docker service file or globally in `/etc/systemd/system.conf`, for example `DefaultStartLimitBurst=100`.

Answer (score 0):

First will only perform one command. Try

```
sudo whoami; whoami
```

Do you want 2 commands with a sleep?

```
echo "whoami; sleep 3; whoami"  > restartDocker
chmod 777 restartDocker
sudo ${PWD}/restartDocker
```